# how can I get correctly the sum of a specific data of an array after a loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hey I have this function:

```
contadorDatosGeneral: function(data){

    var self = this;
    var objProTerminado = {};


        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

            if(data[i].numPorcentajePro == 100){

               objProTerminado.terminados = data[i].numPorcentajePro.length;    

            }

        }
        console.info(objProTerminado);
},
```

In this function I get "data", and in "data" using `console.info(data);` I print the follow:

[image]

So.. I need get how much in "numPorcentajePro" = 100.

In this case I have 4 > 100 and 3 < 100

when I use `console.info(objProTerminado);` print :

> Object {terminados: 3}

But I need:

> Object {terminados: 4} ( becouse exist 4 with 100 );

How can I fix this? sorry my english.

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION** :

With this function work:

```
contadorDatosGeneral: function(data){

    console.info(data);

    var self = this;
    var objProTerminado = new Array;


        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

            if(data[i].numPorcentajePro == 100){


                 objProTerminado.push(data[i].numPorcentajePro);

            }

        }
        console.info(objProTerminado.length);
},
```

Comment: That is because the string `"100"` is 3 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

```
data[i].numPorcentajePro.length;
```

is the length of `data[i].numPorcentajePro`, the length of a string containing `"100"`, which is always `3` characters long.

Instead you need to initialize the counter to zero and add one every time the condition is met.

```
contadorDatosGeneral: function(data){

    var self = this;
    var objProTerminado = {};
    objProTerminado.terminados = 0;


        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

            if(data[i].numPorcentajePro == 100){

               objProTerminado.terminados += 1;    

            }

        }
        console.info(objProTerminado);
}
```